# Swift reload tableview without interrupting a single cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an active observer that will refresh the tableview when new data comes in.

```
ref.child(live_mode).queryOrderedByKey().queryLimited(toLast: 200).observe(.childAdded, with: {snapshot in
            
            self.posts.insert(PostFeed(uid: uid , profile_image_url: profile_image_url, profile_name: profile_name, post_id: post_id, post_title: post_title, post_text: post_text, post_type: post_type, youtube_video_url: youtube_video_url, youtube_video_id: youtube_video_id, youtube_image_url: youtube_image_url, time_stamp: time_stamp, like_count: "0"), at: 0)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 self.tableView.reloadData()
               }
        })
```

I would like the table view to be un-interupted or unrefreshed based on one saved indexPath. Meaning I would like the tableView to be reloaded but I dont want an individual cell reloaded since its playing a video.

```
savedIndex = indexPath // cell to not be reloaded since playing video
```

What is the best way to reload the tableView when new data comes in but without interrupting the saved index cell that would be showing a video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the API to insert single rows

```
ref.child(live_mode).queryOrderedByKey().queryLimited(toLast: 200).observe(.childAdded, with: {snapshot in
        
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.posts.insert(PostFeed(uid: uid , profile_image_url: profile_image_url, profile_name: profile_name, post_id: post_id, post_title: post_title, post_text: post_text, post_type: post_type, youtube_video_url: youtube_video_url, youtube_video_id: youtube_video_id, youtube_image_url: youtube_image_url, time_stamp: time_stamp, like_count: "0"), at: 0)       
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: O, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    }
})
```

The other cells are not affected, and you get a nice animation for free.

If the section is not 0, specify the proper section index.

Comment: Do i need self.tableView.beginUpdates() and self.tableView.endUpdates() before and after the insertRows function? @vadian

Comment: No, you don't need `beginUpdates/endUpdates`. It's only for multiple simultaneous insert/delete/move operations.

Comment: proper format shows this. self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic) do I need to add a counter to accumulate the rows?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `[]`, answer edited. No, just after inserting the item in the data source call this method specifying the insertion location, that's all. If you are going to insert multiple rows, specify all index paths.

Comment: I am getting this runtime crash: Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (38) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out) @vadian

Comment: Is `self.posts` the data source array of `self.tableView`? And is it section 0? If yes and yes the code must work

Comment: Got it, removing dispatch queue was the problem thank you!